# Caps Lock Detection not working

Tags: java, keyboard

When detecting a CAPS LOCK in `Processing Java`, I encountered this error:

```
Cannot find anything named "KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK"
```

I'm pretty sure I can run `Java` methods in `Processing`. The following code below is my import and the variableI set. I think I have everything I need in the import because I imported everything from `Java's AWT`.

```
import java.awt.*;
boolean capsLocked = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Comment: But `KeyEvent` is part of `java.awt.event` package.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan Ok wow, this works. You could post this as an answer you know. thnx alot man.

Comment: for including all the relevant things in the question, especially the imports +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyEvent` is not part of `java.awt` package. It's part of `java.awt.event` package. So you will need to include that package as well.